# Pages showing up in search console as invalid AMP pages even though they amphtml meta tags pointing at valid AMP version

Tags: amp-html

I have this page https://www.timbuktutravel.com/safari/malawi-travel which uses some AMP tags but in the source code points at https://www.timbuktutravel.com/safari/malawi-travel.amp as the amp version of the with the following meta tags:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.timbuktutravel.com/safari/malawi-travel">
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.timbuktutravel.com/safari/malawi-travel.amp">
```

In my Google search console the https://www.timbuktutravel.com/safari/malawi-travel page and other pages like it show up as failing AMP validation. Is there any way to stop this from happening? That page uses some amp technology but there it points at a fully compliant AMP page.

Ideally these pages shouldn't show up in the AMP section of the Google search console. Only their specific AMP versions should be there

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Don't Show the Serach Console why this site are not vilaidate. Usealy the serach console says why if you click on the link in a popup.

Comment: Why use 'some AMP' in the first example? As you know, it's not valid when including the JavaScript. Why not use it as the canonical URL for the valid AMP document? Or maybe I don't understand he question.

Comment: @JayGray There is a canonical page which uses some AMP tags but is not intended to show up through google amp cache. It points at an AMP version which is valid. The problem is that the canonical is showing up as failing AMP validation, when google search console should rather be looking at the amphtml version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.timbuktutravel.com/safari/malawi-travel contains:

```
<html amp= lang="en" amp-version="1496360274808" ...
```

so you are declaring that as an AMP page.

I would advise to make this canonical page as a page with no AMP (remove `amp` from `<html amp` and all the AMP components you are using) and then keep the AMP one and the linking you already have.

Comment: I agree, the non-valid AMP page with JS is confusing (Google). Make one AMP pointing to canonical, and remove all AMP-stuff from canonical.

Comment: Hi, this is great. Thanks, I totally forgot about the amp attribute in the html element